# Why facebook login doesn't ask me for my email and password

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I simply walked through [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/) and [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/personalize/) official facebook tutorial

My email and password are important to be really authenticated, right ?, so why facebook SDK doesn't ask for for them. When i click on login button, it's directly get me logged in and display my name and porfile picture.

I am asking such question because i will integrate the facebook SDK in my application to allow user to log in with Facebook, so i need to understand why the authentification process isn't the standard one which is used on the real Facebook Website? Thanx.

Comment: If you're using iOS 6 and you're logged in, then that's why.

Comment: Yes i am using iOS6, i didn't get your meaning ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS 6.0, you have Facebook in the settings. If you have logged in there then your FB session would be valid(FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) until you logged out. This can get your profile and other default information. Try calling [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation]; from DidApplicationFinishLaunching and it will redirect you to FB login page rather than getting your information and displaying immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Your Internet browser is saving your login information in its cache. Clear history and/or cache and you'll be asked for the login information again.